# Angular ng-show does not show/hide based on function return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

So my angular app is a behemoth, so I pasting the relevant parts here just to see if the Angular Gurus at SO can spot anything that can help me.

I have my HTML code like so:

```
<span class='span_class' ng-show='{{showHideBasedOnFlag(id)}}'>
  ...data...
</span>
```

And in Angular I have:

```
$scope.showHideBasedOnFlag = function(id)
{

   var flag = getFlag(id);
   if(flag == 1) return true; 
   if(flag == -1) return false;
   return true;
}
```

I have three spans,in which the first has a flag of 1 and so should be shown, the other two have flag of -1 so should be hidden. This works as expected when the page loads (first span is show and other two are hidden). But when I examine span 2 and 3, their HTML code looks like follows:

```
<span class='span_class ng-hide' ng-show="false">
```

So my first question is: Is it normal for `ng-hide` to get added by Angular as well as for `ng-show` to be also present? Both are getting added when I have the code `ng-show='{{showHideBasedOnFlag(id)}}'` in my HTML

Secondly and more importantly: I have a button which when clicked, updates the flags for span 2 and 3 to the value of `1`. After this happens, I expected the spans to get shown, they did not. I then explicitly called the `showHideBasedOnFlag` function and console.logged to ensure that the correct true and false were returned by the function. However there is no change my HTML DOM and the spans remain hidden.

I am breaking my head over this, and has run out of ideas.... Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: remove `{{}}` from your code

Comment: @vinayakj: tried that, did not help :(

Comment: ng-show takes in an expression... something like `ng-show="myVar"`, where myVar is either true or false

Comment: @WalksAway the function I call `showHideBasedOnFlag` returns true or false...would that not work?

Comment: it will but you need to remove the `{{}}` like @vinayakj suggested

Comment: @WalksAway I removed that and tried - my code is now `ng-show='showHideBasedOnFlag(id)'` but its still not working...not sure what is wrong

Comment: if it still doesnt work an easy way to debug it is to check the output of the function by adding `{{showHideBasedOnFlag(id)}}` somewhere visible to you so you can  check the value, and if it changes

Comment: check to see if the function is visible to the scope (since the element could be nested in another scope)

Comment: when you are enclosing your function in `{{}}` then its getting resolved to false(according to you) only first time, because thats what expression syntax is used for. What ng-show/ng-hide expects is a expression which which would be true or false, so better use `flag` there.

Comment: paste the function that updates your flags to  value of 1, sounds like you need to wrap the function with a `$timeout`.

Comment: @vinayakj: I understand that now, and I removed the `{{}}`, but did not work..I cannot use the flag directly because other than 1 and -1 there other values based on which the function should return true or false..

Comment: `flag` is just placeholder, use some other variable name which is true/false based on flag value, name based on business logic like `showSeatsView`.. something like that

Comment: what's your getFlag(id) return? did you debug and watched if your function is executing properly? if flag variable is undefined it will break. do you have code on github? it should work withou {{}}

Answer (score 0):

You're interpolating with double brackets. But `ng-show` is not a directive that interpolates a value, it is truthy/falsy based. Therefore, you need a function, so far so good. But in Angular 1.x, directives that are passed a function as written without double brackets.

```
<span class='span_class' ng-show='showHideBasedOnFlag(id)'>
  ...data...
</span>
```

> So my first question is: Is it normal for ng-hide to get added by
>   Angular as well as for ng-show to be also present? Both are getting
>   added when I have the code ng-show='{{showHideBasedOnFlag(id)}}' in my
>   HTML

Yes, this is normal behaviour, as ng-show and ng-hide are complementary switches using the element's visibility property, whereas `ng-if` add or removes the element from the DOM entirely.

Answer (score 0):

When you are enclosing your function in `{{}}` then its getting resolved to false(or whatever initial value is) only first time, because that's what expression syntax is used for. What `ng-show/ng-hide` expects is an expression which would be `true` or `false`, so better use a function or some variable which is changed internally based on condition.

See below example for reference.

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.id;
  
  $scope.showHideBasedOnFlag = function(id) {
    var flag = getFlag(id);
    if (flag == 1) return true;
    if (flag == -1) return false;
    return true;
  }

  function getFlag(id) {
    return id; // just simulation
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Todo</h2>
  <input placeholder="Enter 1 to show -1 to hide" ng-model="id">
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <span class='span_class' ng-show='showHideBasedOnFlag(id)'>
  ...data...
</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're putting `<input>` above the `ngController`... Also instead of 3 lines, could be simply `return flag != -1` in the `function`.

Comment: @developer033 I kept OP's original code so he/she can relate quickly. Sure OP can refactor code